# Clearing Data from Multiple Tables in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have a series of 20 tables on a sheet called "Builder" all with there own individual names. What i want to do is create a variable that isolates only the 19 tables that i tell it to so that i create a `clear content` procedure on them. The 1 remaining table needs to untouched as this table is a overview of the other 19. I have found the below to delete the rows of 1 table but i need to expand it to running the process on multiple.

```
Sub Macro3()
    With Sheets(Builder").ListObjects("P6WC_00002")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
             .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

A few other examples of tables names are: `D86-03116`, `D87-03215`, `F08-00025`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You appear to be missing a double-quote in `With Sheets(Builder")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `For Each` loop, and an Exclusion check:

```
Dim TableToCheck AS ListObject

For Each TableToCheck In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Builder").ListObjects
    If TableToCheck.Name <> "P6WC_00000" Then 'Name of Table you do NOT want to update
        If Not (TableToCheck.DataBodyRange Is Nothing) Then TableToCheck.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
Next TableToCheck
```

Comment: This worked great thank you, but i think there may be something missing. it cleared all the data in the tables but then debugged at `TableToCheck.DataBodyRange.Delete`. Runtime 1004

Comment: @PeterMogford Do you have the full text of the error?

Comment: @PeterMogford There are **dozens** of different causes of a Runtime 1004 error, for example *"Run-time error '1004': Copy Method of Worksheet Class failed"* or *"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"* - what is the full error that shows in the message box?

Comment: _"This Operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet"_

Comment: @PeterMogford This error occurs when 2 tables have a partial (but not complete) overlap in columns:  Deleting data from the Top table tries to shift *some*, but not *all*, of the columns from the Bottom table up, which is an invalid operation.  You may need to rearrange your tables in your Worksheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188427/discussion-between-peter-mogford-and-chronocidal).